# Getting an error when defining a macro in a TiKZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, nodes

I like a certain style of vertices in my Ti*k*Z drawings so I want to define a macro to save time formatting. It has two arguments, one names the node, the next is its location. It should have a blank label. Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
\newcommand{\vertex}[2]{\node[circle, inner sep = 2pt, draw=black, fill=black] (#1) at #2 {}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Placing nodes in upper partition
\foreach \cnt in {1,...,5}
    \vertex{\cnt, (\cnt,0)};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

When I attempt to compile this, I get:

```
Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.
```

The label is there so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problem likely lies in the fact that the macro `\vertex` should be used as `\vertex{<arg1>}{<arg2>}` not `\vertex{<arg1>,<arg2>}`. I recall a similar question, but could not find it right now.

Comment: Yes, you are complicating things. Take a look at the `chains` or the (rather big) `graphs` library. There is surely no need to define a macro to place a few nodes in similar manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro `\vertex` is defined with *two* arguments. But inside the `\foreach` loop, it is given only one argument. Instead, it should be called as `\vertex{\cnt}{(\cnt, 0)}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\vertex}[2]{%
  \node[
    circle,
    inner sep = 2pt,
    draw=black,
    fill=black
  ]
    (#1) at #2 {}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  % Placing nodes in upper partition
  \foreach \cnt in {1,...,5}
    \vertex{\cnt}{(\cnt,0)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

You are complicating life. `tikz` has facilities to define styles via `\tikzset`. So define a style and use it. No need for a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{vertex/.style={
    circle,
    inner sep = 2pt,
    draw=black,
    fill=black
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \cnt in {1,...,5}{
    \node[vertex] (\cnt) at (\cnt,0) {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or use a `pic`.

Comment: Or a simple circle can be filled and the coordinate remembered, ...